# How to join two tables for Report purpose in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have tables like

```
Person{id, name, dob} 
employee{id, company_name, joining_date}.
```

I need to join these two tables for `employee_report` based on common column id.
But i will get

```
employee_report{id,name, dob, company_name, joining_date}
```

But how to map this employee_report? It is querying the database but getting Error : 
Unknow Entity?

How to resolve this.

Comment: Hibernate works with entities and associations between entities. Show us how the entities are mapped, and what you tried to get what you want.

Comment: those are two different entities. No relation between them. For the purpose of report i need to join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no association betwee the entities, the only join you can do with HQL is an inner join using a where clause on the IDs:

```
select person.id, person.name, person.dob, employee.companyName, employee.joiningDate
from Person person, Employee employee
where person.id = employee.id
```

Such a query returns a `List<Object[]>`, each `Object[]` containing the 5 elements you selected.

Comment: can't it return a java object if i use EmployeeReport with all the fields.

Comment: It can if you do `select new com.foo.bar.EmployeeReport(person.id, ...) from ...`, but I find it ugly, because not refactorable. Transforming a `List<Object[]>` into a `List<EmployeeReport>` is a matter of 3 lines of refactorable code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created a view **employee_report**.

You have to create a corresponding Entity in Java code (Ex: EmployeeReport), map it with Hibernate. After that you can get the employee reports from the database.

Comment: what do u mean by map it with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Creating view, sounds convincing. This is what I do for such requirement I encounter in my project.